# Overcrowded German trains

Tags: trains, germany, seating, deutsche-bahn

The recent [spat between Greta Thunberg and German rail](https://www.insider.com/greta-thunberg-claps-back-at-german-railway-over-tweet-2019-12) left me thinking: can you buy a ticket in a German train and not get a seat? Is that only for local or also long haul trains?

Comment: The article cites Thunberg's tweet that "Our train from Basel was taken out of traffic. So we sat on the floor on 2 different trains. After Göttingen I got a seat." Even with a seat reservation, disruptions like these can cause one to be without a seat.

Comment: Sadly this also happens ins Switzerland on the Gotthard lines. Due to security restrictions in this long tunnel they are not allowed to let more people in than there are seats. So sitting on the floor as Greta did is prohibited and you may have to leave the train at the stations before the tunnel if the train is overcrowded and you don't have a reserved seat.

Comment: It deserves mention that even if you happen to have a seat reservation and you catch "your train", it frequently happens that the train is missing car 15 where your reservation was. In many cases it means you will sit on the floor as all other seats in the train are already reserved or occupied. (Another thing that deserves mention: you are rarely sitting alone on the floor like seen i the photo ;))

Comment: It's interesting how the overcrowding is perceived. Sitting on the floor looks bad, but in a really overcrowded train you have to stand - you cannot sit on the floor.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I don't think this is unique to Germany. I've had a seat reservation on a UK train but if they are too full they turn off the reservations (usually on partially commuter trains)

Comment: I remember my mother telling about her travels to and from study in Dresden (from Magdeburg) - she often told that her suitcase never touched the train floor - "always" hanging between passengers' legs in mid air .... comparing that to my picture of current German trains ..they are less crowded compared to say 50 years ago (mainly because nowadays we have 50 million cars compared to way less some time ago)

Comment: @eagle275: Unless she was required to permanently pace up and down the aisles for some reason, I don't understand why she didn't set down her suitcase simply where she was standing, in between the other passengers' feet.

Comment: Reading between lines - the legs were so close together you couldn't shove the suitcase downward - it would hang in midair

Comment: Somewhat related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45576/was-greta-thunberg-forced-to-ride-on-the-floor-of-an-overcrowded-train

Comment: Come on, not every German train is overcrowded. Many of them are so late that passengers have to take another train, some of them simply don't depart at all and some of them even depart 20mins too early.

Comment: Just rent a car.  (Conveniently, they make rather good ones in Germany.)  It's far more convenient in every way, you don't have to pay 100s for a taxi at each end, and if more than about 1 person is traveling it's far cheaper.  Also, in 100.00% of cases you will in fact get a seat as paid for.

Comment: @Fattie excellent points. I have, however, ridden in, and given rides in, passenger vehicles where there were more passengers than seats. _Shhh.... don't tell the cops!_ :)

Comment: Years ago I had a weekly 4-hour train commute through one of the busier lines in Germany. There were times where it was so full that a reservation wouldn't have helped you as you would have had no chance to reach your seat. Standing was one option or leaning upon your piece of luggage. Sitting on the floor was unavailable luxury.

Comment: A few years ago I had tickets for first class on a DB train and the entire carriage my reservation was for had not been attached to the train. Standing for 3 hours in an over-crowded train is NOT fun.

Comment: @Fattie: "Just rent a car. (...) It's far more convenient in every way" - that is a very subjective claim that hinges on lots of personal preferences.

Comment: I think the terminology used in these discussions could be clearer. The train was *crowded* because another train was cancelled, but there was still ample standing room. Around Christmas, trains in the UK risk *overcrowding*. In Japan and India, trains are sometimes *dangerously overcrowded*.

Comment: @DewiMorgan: that seems more precise. Although Greta Thunberg used the word 'overcrowded'. It comes down to a question of expectations. In some countries ppl might have different standards of when a place is packed out.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - hmm, sure; I mean, after *any sentenced typed* one can correctly respond "that is a very subjective claim that hinges on lots of personal preferences".  However it's pretty evident that a private car is more *convenient* than public transport. Pushbike .. car .. train .. plane.  It's a gradient with convenience (zero waiting time, absolute flexibility) on the left and "abstract speed" (much quicker as distances increase by factors of 10) on the right.

Comment: @Fattie: Personally, I find it more convenient that I can read a book/work on a laptop/watch a movie/sleep during a journey, that I can just leave the vehicle without having to search for a parking lot, that I do not have to be constantly attentive about taking the right turns, that I do not have to think about any maintenance tasks of the vehicle (such as refueling), etc. To you, these particular factors may not seem important, but that's just what I wrote: It is not generally evident that a private car is more convenient than public transportation, this depends on individual preferences.

Answer (score 50):

There is no mandatory seat reservation in Germany. The only exception are cross border tickets for some international trains and night sleeper trains. So yes, you can end up with no seat, if the train has no more empty seats.
However in 2017 they introduced a booking limitation for trains that are out of capacity in total. As also standing capacity is limited.

Thus, at least you can get to your destination even in a train without empty seats, contrary to the French system in TGVs, where you just can’t buy a ticket for a train that has no more seats and you have to take the next one with available seats.

Comment: Don't ICEs have mandatory seat reservation?

Comment: No (except for the international ones, as mentioned, and there also only on the part outside of Germany)

Comment: And not even all international ICE's require reservations. Only the ICE to France requires reservation for the French part (because it is treated as a TGV while in France).

Comment: @KristvanBesien The ECE, which is an EC/ICE crossover, has mandatory seat reservations too.

Comment: The ICE Sprinter used to have mandatory reservation but apparently no longer does so.

Comment: In some circumstances it is possible to travel on a full TGV: “Pro” tickets, and overbooked reservations “*sans place assise*” (where the conductor is supposed to help you find a seat, and give you a voucher if none can be found). I’ve done it a few times on the Friday evening Paris–Lyon services...

Comment: @dunni All 1st class tickets (ICE/IC/EC) come with seat reservations included in the ticket price. On these trains seat reservation is also possible to purchase for 2nd class for a few euro.

Comment: The ECE to Milan is the only one with mandatory seat reservation, and that only for trips to/from Italy.

Comment: @Damon, remember the most important rule of this site, 'be nice'. And as you clearly do not often travel in packed trains, there are days you are glad you get enough floor to sit on, when there is standing space only.

Comment: Note that the reservation system is similar to many countries. I.e. in Japan you can buy seats on Shinkansen or many special trains as well as non-reservation tickets. Which means you end up standing if there are no more free seats.

Answer (score 24):

Apart from the exception [dunni](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2998/dunni) mentions, buying a ticket and buying a reservation are completely independent of each other.

Only the cheap tickets (Sparpreis, Super-Sparpreis) have a *Zugbindung*, i.e., they are valid only for one particular train. Normal-price tickets allow you to take any train from starting point to destination, provided it does not have higher category than what you paid for, e.g., IC → ICE (this is within a certain period of time; a couple of days I think). That flexibility would be thwarted if you had to buy a reservation together with the ticket.

This provides for e.g. weekend-commuters who don’t know in advance when they can leave their work at Friday to buy a ticket either without a reservation (and take the risk of travelling in an overcrowded train) or with reservations for different trains (if they are willing to pay for multiple reservations).

Once, when I was buying a ticket at a DB counter, I asked for a seat next to others not yet reserved, because I knew I was going to travel with friends that had not made a reservation. The clerk pointed out that I could make reservations for my friends if I wanted, even though I was just buying one ticket.

Answer (score 9):

Seat reservations in German trains are only a thing in long distance trains (marked EC/IC or ICE if serviced by DB but can also include the Austrian RJ, the French TGV, the Thalys or other European railways’ EC).<sup>[1]</sup> Thus, for any local train trip your ticket comes with no guarantee of a seat.

Where there are seat reservations, these are typically detached from the fare ticket itself. Meaning if you buy a ticket from Munich to Nuremburg and reserve a seat in ICE 4711 but miss that train in Munich central station and end up being in ICE 4713, your fare ticket is still valid but you forfeited your reservation. Note however that most cheaper fares include *Zugbindung* (being bound to a train), meaning that with said cheap fare you must use the train you are booked on.

Standard price tickets (called *Flexpreis*) are not only not restricted to a specific train but also not restricted to a specific train type: you may always travel on lower trains. So if you have an ICE ticket from Munich to Augsburg but taking an IC or a local train is more convenient your ticket is valid (however, if your ticket is an IC ticket you cannot hop onto an ICE barring special circumstances such as a previous delay).

Wherever seat reservations can be made but are not mandatory, they cost EUR 4.50. So a reservation is clearly treated as a separate service.<sup>[2]</sup> It is possible to have your reservation refunded if it is DB’s fault that you can’t take your reserved seat (e.g. if they use a different trainset that doesn’t have seat reservations marked).

Finally, there are a few trains that have mandatory seat reservation, i.e. you must reserve to travel on them and you must sit on your assigned seat (the ticket does not transfer to other trains of the same type). This used to include the ICE sprinter but now is mostly restricted to other railways’ services within Germany if that other railway uses a global pricing system (e.g. TGV, Thalys) and night trains if in a berth.

---

[1]: with a couple of exceptions where local trains apparently allow commuters to reserve a *Stammplatz* (seat you take every time) meaning you would reserve seat 61 in car 6 for the 6:16 train into Munich Mondays to Fridays. Mostly not noticable and not available to the general traveller and I can only remember seeing this service offered by Alex, one of many private local train franchises.

[2]: This is no longer true in first class where a reservation is included in your basic fare ticket. However, unless your basic fare ticket is subject to *Zugbindung* you again do not have to be on the train you reserved.

Answer (score 3):

I've bought tickets in advance and even paid for a seat reservation, but because they had to substitute a different train with either fewer cars or radically different carriage/seat numbering, still been without a seat.

I've been able to get the 4.50 EUR reservation refunded, but not the train ticket itself - when you buy a DB ticket, you're paying for the right to be on the train.

This does not contribute to acceptance of trains as an alternative to driving or flying, so Ms. Thunberg was right to call DB out on this out publicly. Plenty of us less-well-known riders have.

Comment: Ms. Thunberg actually said (or wrote/tweeted) that it was great that so many people were travelling by train. What I find slightly surprising is that considering her fame and fandom, alongside the public knowledge of her world trip without flying, nobody rose to offer her a seat. Or maybe they did and she refused.

Comment: It can be both a great thing that so many people are traveling by train, and DB can still be doing a crap job making sure that they all get seats.

Comment: Indeed.  [*Nobody travels by train anymore, it's too crowded*](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2014/08/29/too-crowded/) ;-)

Comment: @gerrit They did and she didn't refuse. https://twitter.com/DB_Presse/status/1206182674949382145

Comment: @pacholik I meant from other passengers before that.

Comment: @pacholik that tweet refers to a different train she was taking later that day. And she had a regular reservation for that one. The reason she didn't have a reservation on the previous leg was because she wasn't on the train she planned to due to some delay/cancelation.

Comment: You write "when you buy a DB ticket, you're paying for the right to be on the train.", followed by "This does not contribute to acceptance of trains as an alternative to driving or flying" - IMHO it would enhance your answer to explain that conclusion. Of course, paying for bus, tram, train, boat, etc. tickets means you're paying for the right to be on the respective vehicle, what else would you expect to be paying for?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That right, plus a seat reservation?

Comment: @user253751: As far as I can tell, that only ever happens for two reasons: 1) Because standing during the journey is too unsafe. 2) Because the transportation service wants to convey an impression of luxury with their product. Reason 1) applies to planes and long-haul buses, but doesn't apply for trains, boats, or short-haul transportation. Reason 2) is merely a marketing trick to justify high(er) prices. At least in my personal opinion, enjoying the flexbility of having a ticket and being able to spontaneously pick any train that serves the connection is a massive advantage over flying, ...

Comment: ... where you have to nail down the exact date and time of your flight at the time of buying the ticket. That's why I was baffled by the OP's statement and asked for some clarification.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You're correct that letting people stand is more beneficial overall (because more people can travel); other people are correct that it reflects poorly on the mode of transport (because the service would be better if there were more trains instead).

Comment: @user253751: Sure, the two factors that reflect beneficially on the mode of transport are "everyone gets a seat" and "flexibility to spontaneously take any vehicle on the route". Unfortunately, these two factors are a bit at odds with one another, because the former can best be ensured with an accurate prediction of the number of travelers in a given vehicle, which is precisely what's not available if the latter is provided. I see the OP was referring to the impression generated by considering the former factor in isolation (as many travelers would do), rather than the complete picture.

Answer (score 2):

A reservation might be voided if a train is canceled or has less capacity. If too many people are on a train you might need to leave it (in this case they typically prefer people with reservations then).

But while it is a common problem to be in a crowded train and reservations sometimes fails, it needs to be noted that it is also very common that you do get a seat, especially when reserve properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to other fine answers a point of principle:

> left me thinking: can you buy a ticket in a German train and not get a seat?

Yes, as the rationale seems to be: The railway company will not keep you off the train and stuck waiting (sometimes overnight), just because some people aren't willing to sit on the floor. Many people - perhaps most people - don't *like* sitting on the floor, but prefer it to not taking the train; and when a seat is crucial for someone, then they pay for the seat reservation.

This is in no way unique to Germany.

Answer (score 1):

I've travelled extensively for years through all of Germany. Overcrowding is common in both local and long-distance trains. In fact, one Intercity train that I took regularily was often so crowded that I was always afraid I wouldn't be able to get on board at all (always managed, but a few times I had a packed standing place right at the door).

Seat reservations are only for long-distance trains, and even there they aren't mandatory. You can buy a ticket without a seat reservation. In fact, many of the non-budget tickets are not for a specific *train*, but for a specific *route*. So you buy a ticket from, say, Hamburg to Munich on the ICE train - and you can take any ICE within the period you booked for. Especially when I travelled on business, I usually had such flexible tickets as you never know if a meeting runs longer or the trip is cut short.

Also keep in mind that the german train company ("Deutsche Bahn", DB) has been privatized and has since aimed to be "profitable" - mostly by reducing costs. Many trains are planned badly, and even on the trains that are *always* overcrowded, they don't add cars. From the perspective of a profit-driven company, crowded trains are good.